# Work Item ID or Unique ID

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

I'm using TFS 2013. In one field we have a Bug ID.  It's a unique number and people often refer to it when working on projects (e.g., "Did you take care of bug 3456 yet?").  I know we get a Work Item ID with TFS (and that it is a unique number within a Team Project Collection), is there a way I can create a custom field that takes the first initial for the work item type and then attaches an the unique ID to it after? For example, for a bug it could be "B-3456" or for a task it could be "T-4242"? I'm just looking for a better way to way to organize ID numbers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom fields in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157555/custom-fields-in-team-foundation-server)

Comment: I still don't understand what the goal is here. Any time someone is looking at one of these work items, they'll see what type it is. If you export them into an Excel spreadsheet, one of the fields is the work item type. How is prepending a redundant piece of information helping with organization?

Comment: regardless if you don't understand what I'm doing, is what i'm asking possible?

Comment: It's not, which is why I'm trying to drill into the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

> **Work Item ID**
>
> The unique identifier that is assigned to a work item. Work item IDs
>   are unique across all team projects and within a team project
>   collection. Reference name=System.Id, Data type=Integer

If you want to change the work item ID from format "3456"  to "B-3456". It's not able to do this, this ID is stored in TFS database and have various purposes such as work item query, TFS API and so on.

There is no easy Work Item Customization snippet you can apply to a new customize field to have it set to auto increment on save for a specific work item type. If you really want to do this, one way is follow *Jesse Houwing*'s solution in this similar [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38046e8e-5ab9-4290-9a9a-0ba6a8866b57/work-item-id-or-unique-id?forum=tfsworkitemtracking).

And either in VS or in the web portal, it's easy to judge which work item type you are refer to. They have different icons or colors.

[image] [image]

Comment: I'm sorry to ask the question like this instead of in a new question, but I'm almost positive I already know the answer, and I want to be absolutely, 100% sure before I commit to a data structure.

Work Item IDs are unique across all projects. That means that if Project Foo has work item ID #123 , Project Bar (and all other hypothetical projects) can't have a work item ID #123, correct?

Comment: @wanderso Yes, you are right.  The Precondition is project FOO and Project Bar  (and all other hypothetical projects) are not in different team project collection, all located at a same team project collection.